# Is it possible to call DataExtractActivity using WSProxy by using CustomerKey? If not , is it possible to get ObjectId of DataExtractActivity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, wsproxy

Is it possible to call DataExtractActivity using WSProxy by using CustomerKey? If not , is it possible to get ObjectId of CustomerExtract?

Using a Script activity I want to call the DataExtractActivity.

Below is the script.

---

```
 Platform.Load ( "core" , "1.1.5" ) ;
 Write ( "Good Start - Save Trees <br><br>") ;

 Write ( "<br><br>Object ID" + getObjectID ( "<<Passing Here External Key of Data Extract Activity>>" , "DataExtractActivity" ) );

 performDataExtractActivity ("<<Passing Here External Key of Data Extract Activity>>") ;



 function performDataExtractActivity (custKey) {
      var props = {
                     CustomerKey: custKey 
                }; 
      var opts = {};
      var action = "start";
      var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); 
   
      
      try {
           var result = prox.performItem("DataExtractActivity", props, action, opts); 
        
         Write ( "<br><br>" + Stringify(result) ) ;
           //return result.Results[0].Task.InteractionObjectID ;
      } catch ( e ) {
           
           Write ( "<br><br>" + Stringify(e) );
        
       // return "QueryError" ;
        
      }
   
 }


function getObjectID ( queryCustomKey , objectType ) {
   
    var qApi = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
   
    cols = [ "Name", "ObjectID", "CustomerKey" ];
    filter = {
        Property: "CustomerKey",
        SimpleOperator: "Equals",
        Value: queryCustomKey
    };
   
    try {

         var desc = qApi.retrieve(objectType, cols, filter); 
      
         Write ( "<br><br>" + Stringify(desc) + "<br><br>" ) ;
      
    } catch ( err ) {
      
         Write ( "<br><br>" + Stringify (err))
         return "error" ;
         
    }
   
    return desc.Results[0].ObjectID ;
   
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can run via key but you can get the ID via an undocumented REST API endpoint:

```
GET /automation/v1/dataextracts/ 
Host: {{subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{auth}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

You can then run this via WSProxy or via another undocumented REST endpoint:

```
POST /automation/v1/dataextracts/{{dataExtractObjectId}}/actions/start
Host: {{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```